# intercept user call event on android

Tags: android

Is there a way to know in my application when the user initiates a call?

Answer (score 0):

have a look at [this](http://www.krvarma.com/posts/android/detecting-incoming-and-outgoing-calls-in-android/)

- configure permission android.permission.PROCESS_OUTGOING_CALLS
- listen for android.intent.action.NEW_OUTGOING_CALL broadcast